# Do these graphs show normality of model residuals?

Tags: lme4-nlme, multivariate-analysis, residuals, normality-assumption

I have a linear mixed-effects model (lme4 R package) and I am trying to work out whether the model residuals meet the assumption of normality. However, by looking at the graphs below (model residuals versus fitted values, QQplot of model residuals and histogram of model residuals), I cannot decide whether the assumption of normality is met or violated and, especially, whether my model is a acceptable. Can anyone advise please?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Assessing normality via plots tends to be more or less subjective. A histogram of the residuals may make it easier to see any severe deviations from normality. Otherwise, the Shapiro-Wilk test may provide a more objective measure (has it's own limitations).

Comment: How do you do a Shapiro-Wilk test of a linear mixed-effects model?

Comment: Try `shapiro.test(resid(model.name))`

Comment: The question is never is the distribution normal? (because it never is) but is the distribution far from normal in such a way that i need to try to do better with your model. That's still a difficult question. A short if very disappointing answer is that without any details whatsoever on your data or the model specification it is impossible to know whether or how your model might be improved. But -- not to worry overmuch -- normally distributed residuals are -- despite overwhelming usage of the word _assumption_  -- an ideal condition that real data often fail to match.

Comment: I'd reverse the advice of @Jack. Formal tests of normality often just show that you have enough data to detect departure from normality, not that you have a problem. Although there is a chicken and egg question that you need experience with such plots before you can interpret them confidently, the plot is always more informative.

Comment: Knowing very little about how you fit your data and what it looks like after plotting the raw data that produced this model, its impossible to say for certain what is going on here. For starters, it appears you are dealing with discrete data (hence the banded lines), but the lines are also so far apart from each other that they almost seem to represent separate distributions. Your QQ plot is even more confusing because it appears some blue line has been drawn over the middle, but maybe I'm missing something. In any case the QQ plot seems to indicate some *potential* need to look further.

Comment: The last point I made is because even if there was a straight line through the QQ line, the left part of the plot deviates a fair degree away from the "expected" area that it should belong to. Whether that is a problem or not, again, depends on how you fit this model, which requires more information to answer.

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand A close look at the qq plot shows the reference Normal quantiles are on the *horizontal* axis.  Thus, this plot shows both tails of the residual distribution are short, whence there's no sign of any problem at all.

Comment: @whuber thanks for clarifying. That makes sense.